# Reading the pixels values from the Frame Buffer Object (FBO) using Pixel Buffer Object (PBO)

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, fbo, glreadpixels, pbo

Can I use Pixel Buffer Object (PBO) to directly read the pixels values (i.e. using glReadPixels) from the FBO (i.e. while FBO is still attached)?

If yes,

1. What are the advantages and disadvantages of using PBO with FBO?
2. What is the problem with following code

{

```
//DATA_SIZE = WIDTH * HEIGHT * 3 (BECAUSE I AM USING 3 CHANNELS ONLY)
// FBO and PBO status is good
.
.
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fboId);
//Draw the objects
```

**Following glReadPixels works fine**

```
glReadPixels(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, GL_BGR_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,  (uchar*)cvimg->imageData);
```

**Following glReadPixels DOES NOT WORK :(**

```
glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, pboId);
//yes glWriteBuffer has also same target and I also checked with every possible values
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT); 
glReadPixels(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, GL_BGR_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (uchar*)cvimg->imageData);
.
.
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0); //back to window framebuffer
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When using a PBO as target for `glReadPixels` you have to specify a byte offset into the buffer (`0`, I suppose) instead of `(uchar*)cvimg->imageData` as target address. It is similar to using a buffer offset in `glVertexPointer` when using VBOs.

**EDIT:** When a PBO is bound to the `GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER`, the last argument to `glReadPixels` is not treated as a pointer into system memory but as a byte offset into the bound buffer's memory. So to write the pixels into the buffer just pass a 0 (write them to the start of the buffer memory). You can then later acces the buffer memory (to get the pixels) by means of `glMapBuffer`. The example link you provided in your comment does that, too, just read it extensively. I also suggest reading the part about vertex buffer objects they mention at the start, as these lay the ground to understand buffer objects.

Comment: I dont get it, could you please provide me working example code? Because in 'glReadPixels' there is no option to provide offset. And, [the example](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html) dont use any things like you mentioned but still works fine with PBO alone.

Comment: @Rudi I hope you bound the PBO before trying to write into it.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, we can use FBO and PBO together.

**Answer 1:**

**For synchronous reading:** 'glReadPixels' without PBO is fast.

**For asynchronous reading:** 'glReadPixels' with 2/n PBOs is better- one for reading pixels from framebuffer to PBO (n) by GPU and another PBO (n+1) to process pixels by CPU. However fast is not granted, it is problem and design spefic.

**Answer 2:**

Christian Rau's explanation is correct and revised code is below

```
glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, pboId);
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT);
//glReadBuffer(GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT);

glReadPixels(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

//GLubyte* src = (GLubyte*)glMapBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, GL_READ_ONLY_ARB);
//OR
cvimg->imageData = (char*) glMapBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, GL_READ_ONLY_ARB);
if(cvimg_predict_contour->imageData)
{
  //Process src OR cvim->imageData
  glUnmapBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB);     // release pointer to the mapped buffer
}
glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, 0);
```