# error 0x0502 when reading pixels to PBO from FBO

Tags: android, opengl, fbo, pbo

I was trying to use FBO and PBO together, read pixels from FBO to PBO, everyframe.
Codes are below:

```
//at the beginning:
//fbo
glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_fBO);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_fBO);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid, 0);
//pbo
glGenBuffersARB(1, &m_pbo);
glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, m_pbo);
glBufferDataARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, DATA_SIZE, 0, GL_STREAM_READ_ARB);

//at each frame:
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_fBO);
Draw_some_stuff();
glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, m_pbo);
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT);
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glReadPixels(0, 0, m_width, m_height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);   //err occurs
Ptr = glMapBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, GL_READ_ONLY_ARB);
Cpu_works_on_Ptr();
glUnmapBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB);
```

It works fine on PC. But failed to running on my android phone, got an error 0x0502(GL_INVALID_OPERATION) right after glReadPixels.

I believe my codes are the same as the bottom answer at this link: 
[Reading the pixels values from the Frame Buffer Object (FBO) using Pixel Buffer Object (PBO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144268/reading-the-pixels-values-from-the-frame-buffer-object-fbo-using-pixel-buffer)

Has anyone got a clue? Where did I do it wrong?

Comment: How did you get this to build on Android? I don't think it would have those ARB extensions defined.

Comment: Many of those functions might be extensions on Android (`glMapBuffer` and `glUnmapBuffer`, for example, which are part of [`GL_OES_mapbuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_mapbuffer.txt)), but they should have the **OES** suffix instead of **ARB**. _That is a mystery..._